# Properties of a symmetric, positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

> Consider symmetric, positive definite matrix $B \in \mathbb{R^{n \times n}}$. Show that the following holds
>   $$|b_{ij}| \leq \sqrt{b_{ii} \cdot b_{jj}} \leq \frac{1}{2} (b_{ii} \cdot b_{jj}) $$

---

How can I do that?

Comment: A matrix with the same number of rows and columns

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: Yes you are right. Sorry:(

Comment: You can use this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion (focus on the 2x2 case)

Comment: So I can state that every 2 by 2 submatrix is positiv definite and then?

Comment: It is positive definite

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3018654/42969.

Comment: The second inequality is false when $B=I$.

Comment: The first inequality is Cauchy-Schwarz, and as pointed out by user1551, the second inequality as currently written is mistyped, though I'd wager it's meant to be GM $\leq$ AM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to show that this condition holds directly. Let $e_1,\dots,e_n$ denote the standard basis (so that $e_i$ is the $i$th column of the identity matrix). By definition, it holds that $x^TBx \geq 0$ for any vector $x \in \Bbb R^n$.

Now, take $x = t e_i + t^{-1} e_j$ (for $t \neq 0$) and write out the expression $x^TBx$ as a function of $t$. Using the fact that $x^TBx$ is positive for all choices of $t \in \Bbb R\setminus \{0\}$, reach the desired conclusion about the entries $b_{ii},b_{ij},b_{ji},b_{jj}$.

Comment: I see: you get 2 by 2 sub matrix. But how can you conclude that the determiant is >0.

Comment: @Max I don't know what you mean by "you get a $2 \times 2$ submatrix". $x^TBx$ is a number, not a matrix.

Comment: Don't you get something like that: $$
x^TAx = a_{ii} x_{i}^2 + a_{jj} x_j^2 + 2 a_ia_j x_ix_j = \pmatrix{x_i & x_j}\pmatrix{a_{ii} & a_{ij}\\a_{ij} & a_{jj}}\pmatrix{x_i\\x_j}
$$

Comment: For $x = x_i e_i + x_j e_j$+

Comment: @Max Yes, you could write $x^TAx$ in that form (and that is what I recommend in the post that Martin linked).  However, in my answer here, I tell you to do something different.

Comment: I see you write $x^T Bx$ as a function of t, but how do you get to the inequality in detail?

Comment: @Max Try to figure that out on your own

Comment: Yes I will do that. Thank you for your help:)